# In Out Patameters In Dynamic Set DB2

Tags: db2

my table is aaa (a char(5))

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE zzz ()
         DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
     P1: BEGIN
        Declare cID char(5) ;
        Declare cc char(5) ;
        Declare csql varchar(200) ;
        Declare s1 varchar(200) ;

         Set cID = 'a' ;

         SET Csql = 'SET ? = (select a from aaa where a = :cID)' ;

          PREPARE S1 FROM Csql  ;       
          EXECUTE S1 into cc using cID ;     {error this line}

           print (cc) ;
    END P1
```

I get error  :

Deploy [sss]A.ZZZ
Running A.ZZZ - Deploy started. Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601. A.ZZZ: 14: An unexpected token "" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: "S1 into cc using cID".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56 An unexpected token "" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: "S1 into cc using cID".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56 A.ZZZ - Deploy failed. A.ZZZ - Roll back completed successfully.

Comment: Learn how to write routines by studing working examples here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=api-sql-pl-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems.

- `S1` must either have the `STATEMENT` type or not be declared at
  all, but not be declared as `VARCHAR`.
- `print (cc)` is not a valid statement at all.
  If you want to have some debug output, read about
  [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dom-put-line-procedure-put-complete-line-in-message-buffer).
  The tool you call your routine from must have an ability to display
  contents of the message buffer.
- Your routine doesn't return any
  cursors to caller / client. There is no need to use the  `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1` clause. This problem is not critical.

Comment: show me the tool to display contents . SQLscript is not supported

Comment: Db2 Command Line Processor (CLP). Actually, you may implement such a display on your own with routines of the dbms_output module as in the [example](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dom-get-line-procedure-get-line-from-message-buffer).