# Dynamic cursor variable in DB2

Tags: db2

I want to open a dynamic cursor variable.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TTT ()

    P1: BEGIN
          Declare cID char(5) ;
          declare c1 cursor for s1 ;        
          declare stmt  varchar(1000) ;
   
          set cid = 'a' ;
         
          Set stmt = 'select * from aaa where a = ?' ;
          prePare s1 from stmt ;
   
   
          open c1 using cid ;

    END P1
```

I get error :

A.TTT - Deploy started.
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
A.TTT: 6: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56
An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56
A.TTT - Deploy failed.
A.TTT - Roll back completed successfully.

Comment: begin with adding a colon to your variable : `prePare s1 from :stmt ;`

Comment: There is no such meaning as "dynamic cursor variable" in db2. You return a result set from SP in your example without any variables. There is another technique of working with result sets based on [Cursor types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=spdt-cursor-data-types), where cursor variables are used.

Comment: @ThomasG This is a erroneous suggestion. Such a syntax is not supported in Db2 SQL/PL.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. [In Out Patameters In Dynamic Set DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749647/in-out-patameters-in-dynamic-set-db2)  You can edit your question and add additional information if you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the code ignores the documented rules for the order of statements in a compound-SQL block.

One of the rules is that the cursor declaration(s) must appear after all other declared variables and before the start of the SQL PL code block.

So in your question, the order of the variables should be:

```
  Declare cID char(5) ;
  declare stmt  varchar(1000) ;
  declare c1 cursor for s1 ;
```

For Db2-LUW at current version these rules for compound SQL blocks are [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled).

To return a resultSet to the caller or the client, remember to add `with return to caller` or `with return to client` in the `declare c1 cursor`  line,  along with adding `dynamic result sets 1` in the procedure definition.

To consume the cursor (i.e. to fetch from it) inside the stored procedure code then you do not need these things.

Your jdbc driver is very old, so plan to upgrade it to a better supported version. You can download the latest versions via this site https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads

You can also make the error messages more verbose by appending an additional attribute to the connection string URL  `;retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;`

This can speed up your ability to solve trivial programming problems when learning.

Comment: Please show me the chance to use `with return to caller` or `with return to client`. I write `declare c cursor with return to client for select * from aaa` , i get error when deploying